# Remove the trailing time zone(UTC) in timestamp column in big query

Tags: datetime, google-cloud-platform, time, google-bigquery

Sep 14, 2023 @ 13:08:53.588 ( This is in string format in Bq column 'timestamp')
and I have used the below code to convert it to timestamp

> SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%E*S',timestamp)
> which gives me 2023-09-14 13:08:53.587000 UTC.

But I want to remove the trailing time zone (in this case UTC) as it is wrong. Could you please guide me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you probably just want to use the `DATETIME` datatype and `PARSE_DATETIME` function. `TIMESTAMP` in BQ is UTC by definition.

Some examples of the two and converting between timezones below. Both accept a timezone argument, but do different things.

- `DATETIME('2008-12-25 05:30:00', 'America/Los_Angeles')` converts *from* UTC *to* LA
- `TIMESTAMP('2008-12-25 05:30:00', 'America/Los_Angeles')` converts *from* LA *to* UTC

```
WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT 'Sep 14, 2023 @ 13:08:53.588' as test_col
)

SELECT
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%E*S', test_col) AS utc_timestamp, -- assumes string input is already in UTC
  PARSE_DATETIME('%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%E*S', test_col) AS test_datetime, -- not timezone aware
  
  TIMESTAMP(
    PARSE_DATETIME('%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%E*S', test_col),
    'Australia/Brisbane'
  ) AS utc_from_brisbane_timestamp, -- input is in Brisbane time, convert to UTC using the TIMESTAMP function and timezone argument

  DATETIME(
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%E*S', test_col),
    'Australia/Brisbane'
  ) AS brisbane_from_utc_datetime -- input is in UTC, convert to Brisbane using the DATETIME function and timezone argument

FROM test_data
```